# fetch first five posts using tumblr API

Tags: php, api, tumblr

```
$feedURL = 'http://########.tumblr.com/api/read/';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);

foreach($xml->posts->post as $post){
   $posts = (string) $post->{'photo-caption'}; 
   $img = (string) $post->{'photo-url'};
   echo "<div style='width:518px;height:300px;'><div style='width:200px;height:200px;float:left;'>".'<img style="width:200px;height:200px;" src="' . $img . '" />'."</div><div style='width:300px;float:right;'>".$posts."</div></div><br>";
}
```

I have used this code to display all the available posts, but i want to display just first five posts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According [to the tumblr API](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api), you can append a querystring parameter `num` to limit the number of posts returned from the API call.  I have no personal experience with the Tumblr API, but you might try something like this to limit the number of posts read:

```
$numPosts = 5;
$feedURL = "http://########.tumblr.com/api/read/?num=$numPosts";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
// etc. etc.
```

Comment: @user799100 Change the single quotes to double quotes around the `$feedURL`

Comment: A side note, the limit on how many post you can return appears to be 50, see https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tumblr-api/RmLUlbULZbI/40Wx-CToQHkJ

Answer (score 1):

Read API docs. http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api#api_read

If you give `?num=5` you'll get 5 results.

On the other hand you can use the following:

```
$posts = $xml->posts->post;
$posts = array_slice($posts, 0, 5);
```